# How to implement simple factory with Autofac or Unity in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, autofac

Consider this example:

Cargo class(table) which is the parent table of

```
Container,Bulk,Others  and so on.
```

There is a View with a drop down CargoType that has values:  Container,Bulk,Others etc

I would like to get the instance of either of the above related child class based on the value of CargoType dropdown:

[image]

On the left is what goes into Cargo class (table) on the right is what goes into the subclass (the right pane changes on changing the Type dropdown on the left.)

My question is how do I create an instance of the Cargo and its subclass in the ActionMethod?

```
ActionMethod Create(Cargo cargo)
{
  if(cargo.type==0)
  {
     Container container=new Container();
     //and then use TryUpdateModel() with formscollection to fill container object
  }else
  .....
}
```

What would be a better way? How do I do it using autofac or unit(preferably autofac) ? I am using EF6 code first.

Comment: Using Factory together with IoC container is a matter of opinion... personally I agree with [Nikola Malovic](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/): "IMO, using factories together with IoC doesn’t make a lot of sense because IoC container is in a sense “universal abstract factory"

Comment: @HoomanBahreini My question is how do I achieve same behavior with autofac? I mean I want to replace this factory that I have shown. I want to remove the if consitions. I want to be able to just write some parent class or interface in the action and it should automatically create instance of Container,Bulk etc depending on the typeof Cargo